# how to get the modified value of property after the feature is installed?

Tags: properties, installshield

I have used a dialog in `OnFirstUIBefore()` for users to input some information, 
and stored them in property `USERINF`.

However, when I want to retrieve the value of `USERINF` inputted by user in `feature_installed()`,
what I get is a default value.

I have added the `USERINF` to `SecureCustomProperties` property, but still cannot get the modified value.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've always written values like these to the registry, then used appsearch to get them out into the property again.

There is no built in way to persist values like these built into MSI.